# RegEx to match on string excluding underscores

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check if two strings match. The first string will not contain underscores the other will. Removing the underscores from the second string would result in the strings being equivalent. Can I perform this check using the Regex.Match() method?

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
my_table == mytable;
db_rv_term == dbrvterm;
```

So I just want to match the two strings excluding the underscores.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, regular expressions aren't the right tool. You would have to do something equivalent to `_*m_*y_*t_*a_*b_*l_*e_*`. Clearly that's not a good idea. Try:

```
if (str1 == str2.Replace("_", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regular expressions.

Instead, you can call `Replace`:

```
if (str1.Replace("_", "") == str2)
```